# Storing an object in a list, then making changes to the object

Tags: java, list, data-structures, reference, storage

I have an object which I add to a `List` using the method `theList.add(theObj)`.

If I now make changes to this object `theObj`, will these changes always be reflected in the object stored in the list?

If yes, does this mean that `List` in java stores only references and not unique copies of the objects it is passed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't store an *object* in the list. You store a *reference* in the list.

And yes, if you make a change to the object via *any* reference, that change will be visible however else you get to the same object.

The same is true for assignment, argument passing etc:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder builder2 = builder;

builder.append("foo");
System.out.println(builder2); // Prints foo
```

Here the values of `builder` and `builder2` are references to the same `StringBuilder` object - so having appended a string to the data in the object via `builder`, you can reach the same information via `builder2`.

Comment: Do ALL data structures in the Java Collections framework behave this way?

Comment: @Shailesh: It's nothing to do with the Java *collections* specifically - it's how *all* of Java works. The value of a variable is never an *object*; it's always either a primitive value or a reference.

Comment: Thanks. That gave me a lot of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

> If yes, does this mean that List in
>   java stores only references and not
>   unique copies of the objects it is
>   passed?

Well, it will make a copy if you're using primitives.  And possibly strings.